# Conditional Aggregate Lookup - SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, aggregate, lookup

I have a report with two datasets to summarise the number and value of incomplete orders by status. I have a "Back Order" column, which is using the 'Lookup' function to refer to a second database, based on a whether the Fields!IsBackorder.Value returns true. This works at line level, but I've run into issues at the aggregate level.

For the total count of orders, this forumula works:

```
=SUM(IIF(LOOKUP(Fields!SalesOrderID.Value, Fields!SalesOrderID.Value, Fields!IsBackorder.Value, "DstBackorders") = "TRUE",1,0))
```

However, for the total value of orders ("Fields!NetValue.Value"), this returns '#Error'

```
=SUM(IIF(LOOKUP(Fields!SalesOrderID.Value, Fields!SalesOrderID.Value, Fields!IsBackorder.Value, "DstBackorders") = "TRUE",Fields!NetValue.Value,0))
```

I've tried custom aggregate functions but I haven't found any that work. I'm not sure how I'm getting this error.

Any suggestions would be really helpful.

Thanks,

[Report Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhr9w.jpg)

Comment: Just some thoughts.... What datatype is NetValue? What happens if you swap out NetValue with say '1'? If this gives you a count then it could be a scope problem in which case you might need to specific the dataset that NetValue comes from

Comment: Thanks Alan, I used the CDec() function to convert both numbers to a decimal and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax looks perfectly fine , also the lookup looks good , can you please check on the below things in your DataSet:

1. Is Fields!NetValue.Value in scope of the current DataSet.
2. Are we using the correct data type for Fields!NetValue.Value(Something which is aggregatable , like int , decimal etc.)

Comment: Thank you. The issue was having two data types int & decimal. I used the CDec() function to convert both numbers to a decimal and it worked a treat. 
                                                          
                                                          
=Sum(IIf(LOOKUP(Fields!SalesOrderID.Value, Fields!SalesOrderID.Value, Fields!IsBackorder.Value, "DstBackorders") = "TRUE", CDec(Fields!NetValue.Value) , CDec(0.00)))